# How can I rebuild the source files for a Java web app?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I have a running Java web application from a previous employee which I am trying to fix. I literally just need to fix one line in .java file. However, I have problems rebuilding it and running the new version with Tomcat. When I try to rebuild the files, it doesn't actually change any of the source files.

I'm at a bit of a loss when it comes to going about recompiling/rebuilding the .java files. Do I need any additional tools for it?

Comment: Is there a build script for the app?  Maybe a `pom.xml` (maven) or a `build.xml` (ant) or a `build.gradle` (gradle) file in there?

Comment: @David Yeah, there is a `build.xml` file in a folder called `WEB-INF`. What exactly should I do with it? The other files aren't there.

Comment: import project in your IDE and add ant task then run build.xml to build your project

Comment: If it works let me know

Comment: @Spara Thanks! I followed your suggestions and it seems to be rebuilt. However, I think tried to replace the entire `WEB-INF`  folder with the updated one, and now it crashes.

Comment: what is the error then?

Comment: did you tried to just replace your new java class file to old `WEB-INF` folder?

Comment: @Spara Ok I tried it and now it doesn't crash. I'll let you know if it works like that. Feel free to add this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the project in to an IDE and add ant task then run `build.xml` to build your project. After that you can change your java class and build the project then get the class file and replace it into old project